# Terraform: How to create a api gateway POST method at root?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to create POST method using terraform at the root api gateway URL such as https://somehash.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev which would include the stage. Here is part of the terraform plan of concern:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "api" {
  name = "submit-dev-gateway-api"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "resource" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id}"
  parent_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.root_resource_id}"
  path_part = "submit"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "post_form" {
  rest_api_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id}"
  resource_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.resource.id}"
  http_method   = "POST"
  authorization = "NONE"
}
...
```

I tried changing the path_part to "/" but it did not work. I could not create a aws_api_gateway_method resource without aws_api_gateway_resource. I can create a POST at root manually without terraform which looks like this:
[image: manual]

When I use the above terraform plan I get this:
[image: terraform]

How do I create POST at root with terraform?

Comment: What if you remove `path_part = "submit"` from terraform script?

Comment: I get this error: `The argument "path_part" is required, but no definition was found.`

Comment: Try putting `path_part = ""` or `path_part = "\"`

Comment: Got this error for empty string `BadRequestException: Resource's path part must be specified`. `"\"` is same as `"/"`. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The "root resource" is created automatically as part of creating an API Gateway REST API. In Terraform, the id of that root resource is exposed as [the `root_resource_id` attribute](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/api_gateway_rest_api.html#root_resource_id) of the REST API resource instance.

Because that resource is implicitly created as part of the API, we don't need a separate resource for it. Instead, we can just attach methods (and the other necessary downstream objects) directly to that existing root resource:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "api" {
  name = "submit-dev-gateway-api"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "post_form" {
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id
  resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.root_resource_id
  http_method   = "POST"
  authorization = "NONE"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must check `path_part`. 
Try

```
path_part   = "{submit}"
```

The path_part argument will contain a string that represents the endpoint path. Read more [path_part](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/api_gateway_resource.html#path_part)

Comment: It works functionally but does not get the desired result as I do when I manually create the POST method in the AWS console. I also need to add a string after stage URI. Unfortunately aws_apigatewayv2_api resource is not available yet https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/apigatewayv2_api.html otherwise it is exactly what I need.